# How to get expired date of user domain

Tags: c#, active-directory, dns

My application (C#) use user & password domain to authorise when user login, domain has max password age policy, i want notify to user number of day will expire their password (like when login to windows). Can I do that if i don't have domain admin account.

P/s : i'm using UserPrincipal to verify user & password domain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it, here is [How Long Until My Password Expires?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974598.aspx) article from Microsoft.

JP